# Fork three independent processes that interact through pipes, wait for them to finish, then print terminate messages

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

So my programming assignment is to:

- create 3 independent processes
- have them send data to each other through pipes
- when final data is sent, each of the three process will print their PID.

My question is, how do I get the processes to hold off so that the other processes can finish their tasks before terminating?

Is there a signal I need to send if the child is waiting?

Right now, I've got something like...

```
p1 = fork();
// For the first process
if (p1 == 0) {
    // For the second process
    p2 = fork();
    if (p2 == 0) {
        // For the third process
        p3 = fork();
        if (p3 == 0) {
        }
    }

}

// This is the parent
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your first child is forking the second child which is forking the next child, etc.

Is this really what's required here? It's difficult to say...is the parent supposed to have 3 direct children, siblings?

Here you're forking off this sort of ancestry,a child aving a child...parent with a grandchild, etc. If this is how it's supposed to be then the parent must wait for the first child to return...the first child must wait for it's child to return, and so on.

As for them outputting their PID...I'd say it was a simple case of having each individual child process output its PID.

All these things can be read about in great detail in the man pages and probably whatever coursework or lectures you attended prior to being given your assignment.

Best of luck.